# Is it possible to generate an OpenAPI YAML file from annotated source files via openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

Is it possible to generate an OpenAPI YAML file from annotated source files via the openapi-generator-maven-plugin and the generator openapi-yaml?
The Maven plugin as well as CLI tool require an input-spec and only generate from that, not from soruce files. I've searched the (sadly sparse :() documentation and so far found nothing.

Additionally, if this isn't possible (which is likely I guess), is there any other possibility? This project is sadly non-Spring so using springdoc is no alternative.

Thanks!

Comment: What non-Spring framework do you use? There's [Swagger Core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core) for JAX-RS.

Comment: We're using JAX-RS and the swagger-jaxrs dependency but the delivery of the json/yaml documentation is some custom handwritten ****. I guess I'd be best off just copying the code where Swagger generates the yaml file :/

Answer (score 0):

No. As you found out the plugin requires a YAML as input which kind of defeats the purpose.

If you use springdoc, there is a workaround.

Create a spring context, then get the bean `OpenApiWebMvcResource`. This is the servlet which returns the YAML when you download it from the Swagger UI.

You can then create a mock GET request for

```
"${Constants.DEFAULT_API_DOCS_URL}${Constants.DOT}${Constants.YAML}"
```

(import org.springdoc.core.Constants)

which you can execute by calling

resource.openapiYaml(request, yamlUrl, Locale.ENGLISH)

This returns the YAML as string.

You will need a small Configuration bean to set some defaults:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@Import(
    value = [
        OpenApiWebMvcResource::class,
        SpringDocWebMvcConfiguration::class,
    ]
)
internal class ExportYamlTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun springDocConfigProperties() = SpringDocConfigProperties().apply {
        isWriterWithDefaultPrettyPrinter = true
        isWriterWithOrderByKeys = true
    }

    @Bean
    fun mvcConversionService() = DefaultFormattingConversionService()

    @Bean
    fun springWebProvider() = SpringWebMvcProvider()
}
```

and spring-test on the classpath for MockHttpRequest.